# Accessing inherited entities of EF in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm getting started on EF (6.0) and have a quick question:

I used the model first approach to design an entity model that includes an entity named "Component". I then created several entities that inherited from this base type, such as "VideoCard".

Now in my ASP.net codes, I have access to context.Components, but I cannot seem to directly return context.VideoCards. So if I want to return a list of video cards only, should I use something like

```
 context.Components.OfType<VideoCard>();
```

(tried this it seems to work), or is there something else I should know on this topic?

Edit: I realized that this also works:

```
context.Components.Where(x => x is VideoCard);
```

Is one of these approaches better than the other?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose `VideoCards` property in you context and get only `VideoCard` entities via it.

```
public class MyContext
{
  public DbSet<Component> Components { get; set; }
  public DbSet<VideoCard> VideoCards { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like below

```
var allVideoCards = context.VideoCards.ToArray();
```